# Replacing the SSIS SharePoint List Source

Tags: rest, 2016, odata, ssis

Hi I've been trying at this now for a day or so but it's proving really difficult.
I've got a basic SSIS package which essentially queries some SharePoint lists (lists with files) and drags out the data in a SQL table for reporting.

Previously this was done with the SSIS SharePoint list adapter, but I've been told to now go for the OData or perhaps the web API.

All is well, however I'm missing several properties in the OData.

- Check In Comment
- Edit
- File Size
- Folder Child Count
- Item Child Count
- Type
- Some custom fields.

I've been a bit stuck on the check in comments but even something like expanding the checked out to:

```
URL/DocumentTypes?$select=CheckedOutTo&$expand=CheckedOutTo
```

Seems to remove the information that was previously there and also seems to naff up the OData source editor in the SSIS package.

I was hoping for a nice editor to help me out with this but there doesn't seem to be one.

Any help out there?